# select value in select box other value in array will appear in the input field

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array data below:

```
<?php
  $names = array('Ireneo Crodua' => array('Australia', 'contact 3883 441', 'id_01'), 
                 'Almads Bangal' => array('India', 'contact 3883 811', 'id_02' ),
                 'Rechard Canonigo' => array('America', 'contact 3883 333', 'id_03'),
                 'Marjohn bebeloni' => array('China', 'contact 3883 444', 'id_04')
  );

?>
```

I have a select box to select the name of the person

```
<form action="post">

  <p><label>Select Name</label>
    <select>
      <?php 
        foreach($names as $name => $place){
          echo "<option>" . $name . "</option>";
        }
      ?>

    </select>
  </p>


  <p><label>Place</label><input name="place" value="" /></p>
  <p><label>Contact</label><input name="contact" value="" /></p>
  <p><label>ID Number</label><input name="id_number" value="" /></p>


</form>
```

is that posible if I select for example `Rechard Canonigo` in my select box the array value for `Rechard Canonigo` will appear automatically in input field.

**example:**

America will automatically appear in `input field => place` and `contact 3883 333` will also appear in `input field => contact` and the last the `id_03` will appear in `id_number` input field

**I fount this jquery code:**

```
$(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
     $('input[name=place]').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

work similar in what i want to achieve but the problem is it only give one result in the array

Comment: a good start, unless you want to use xhr is to convert your PHP array to JS.. or json.. hey, isn't there a function for that..

Comment: that array is actually a field in my `mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its, quite possible, you already got the first field working. For the second and third field, you could import those array inside javascript thru the use of `json_encode()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var names = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>; // put it inside
$(function(){
    $('select').on('change',function(){
        // on select change
        var selected_value = $(this).val();
        $('input[name=place]').val(selected_value);
        // since the selected value is a key just point it to the object and get its values
        $('input[name=contact]').val(names[selected_value][1]);
        $('input[name=id_number]').val(names[selected_value][2]);
    });
});
</script>
```

[Sample Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/p7qn13)

Comment: thank you for you brilliant answer, in my situation that array is actually from my database i use mysql it that possible also to work?

Comment: @IreneoCrodua yes it will work, its just important to use that `json_encode()` since you'd want that inside the javascript to be used. Actually the proper way here is to just implement an ajax request on select change especially when the PHP is not on the same page, but this way will also work just fine if they are on the same page.